# Flyway migration with multiple instances pointing at the same schema

Tags: java, oracle, flyway

We are not using Flyway yet, but I am researching it now in the hopes of implementing it in the next few months.

We would like to have the application run the migration check at startup.  However we have two different apps working together in the same database, and multiple instances of each.  my *hope* is that the first one through the gate will add a **Pending** record to the history table and the others will not also try to upgrade seeing that.

Is that a realistic expectation?
Can we rely on that mechanism?
How do others handle this?
Thanks.

Comment: it might matter where you deploy your application, and if flyway allows you to do those things manually, like providing you a Session

Comment: I haven't seen the concept of sessions in Flyway yet.  Will research that. Thanks.

Comment: I believe, and I may be wrong, that it doesn't work like this. The updates to the table that marks what has been successfully deployed doesn't happen until it completes. I'm going to contact some developers who work on the code to validate.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the database. Those that support explicitly taking and releasing table locks via the JDBC driver should lock the history table at the start of a migration, thereby blocking any other Flyway instances from proceeding, and release the lock at the end. There are a couple of databases we know of (CockroachDB is one) which don't allow this, and for them a Pending row in the database is inserted and then deleted.

Comment: We're using Oracle.  I don't see any mention of that on https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle#driver. Is there some other place I can verify how the table locking on migrate will work in Oracle?  Thanks!

Comment: how about a real documentation/example from flyway's side? _should lock_ is not ideal either, I would expect a stronger enforcement (where available) and proper documentation (and it lacks).

Comment: @dj_segfault if you are on Oracle you have other (Oracle specific) problems with migration rollbacks: https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/learn-more/frequently-asked-questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-DoesFlywayperformarollbackifamigrationfails?

Answer (score 2):

As per flyway's offical [faq](https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/learn-more/frequently-asked-questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-Canmultiplenodesmigrateinparallel?), they fully support cluster (multi node app instances).

> Yes! Flyway uses the locking technology of your database to coordinate multiple nodes. This ensures that even if multiple instances of your application attempt to migrate the database at the same time, it still works. Cluster configurations are fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

The [flyway download page](https://flywaydb.org/download) claims "Safe for multiple nodes in parallel" as one of their features. I've read they use locks to achieve this.